# Passing a reference of a data collection into a click handler's callback function

Tags: jquery

Here's how my code is structured at the time being:

```
$.post('includes/getPeople.php', {char: character}, function(data) {
 var peopleData = data.people;

 //generation of HTML markup...

 $("#peopleTable a.nameLink").live("click", function(e) {
 var index = $(this).attr("title");
 console.log(peopleData[index].Email);
 alert(peopleData[index].Email);
 e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Whenever I click on a link (which is the name of the person in the database), I get this error: "peopleData is undefined". Is there a way I could fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.live()` in that context isn't correct, and it is most likely why you are having this error. You should use `.bind()` instead.

- [Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [Bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

If you check their description, you will notice that `live` is a form of extension of `bind` where each time a new HTML element is added that matches the selector in `live`, the event handler will automatically be "binded".

In your case, each time you are making the AJAX call, you are calling the `.live()` function which is causing adding a new handler to the links each time your HTML markup is created.

Hope it made sense, tried my best to explain.

**EDIT:**

Looking at the code, it appears that peopleData is out of context now, so it doesn't exist. The variable is created inside the post callback function, while the click event handler is outside the function.

Try the following:

```
$(function() {
    var letters = $("ul#peopleLetters li");
    var current = $("ul#peopleLetters li.selected");
    var d = '';
    retrievePeople('#');
    letters.click(function() {
        d = $(this).attr("title");
        current.removeClass("selected");
        current = $(this);
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        retrievePeople(d);
    });

    function retrievePeople(character) {
        $.post('includes/getPeople.php', {char: character}, function(data) {
            var peopleData = data.people;
            var count = data.count;
            var markup = '';
            var countDetails = '';
            countDetails = (character == '#') ? count + " Listings Were Found." : count + " Listing(s) Beginning With The Letter '" + character + "'";
            if(count == 0){ markup = "No results were found.";}
            else {
                //markup stuff [although, a note here, instead of using data.people, you can, and should use peopleData]
            }

            $("#peopleTable a.nameLink").bind("click", {data: peopleData}, function(e) {
                var index = $(this).attr("title");
                console.log(data[index].Email);
                alert(data[index].Email);
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        $("#allPeople").html(markup);   
        }, "json");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I think I got what you're trying to say but using .bind() did not really solve the problem. I'm still getting "peopleData is undefined". Here's my code: 
$("#peopleTable a.nameLink").bind("click", {data: peopleData}, function(e) {
 var index = $(this).attr("title");
 console.log(data[index].Email);
 alert(data[index].Email);
 e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: @Kassem Any chance you might edit your post and put the whole JS code there? maybe something is clearing the variable. Although, in the code u copied in the comment above, you are using `data` while you should be using `peopleData`

Comment: here's the full code: http://pastebin.com/C0WeMEhC. But why should I be using peopleData instead of data?

Comment: Ok I got it sorted out... it was because I was placing the function outside the handler... check out the correction: http://pastebin.com/dKjYZjQ2. But I'm still not sure that's the best way of doing this, are there any better ideas?